# There's no line here to end \maketitle

Tags: titles

[image]
So, I was given this template to work off.Everything is done but then I noticed my acknowledgement was before the title page of the thesis. I tried executing it but I keep getting the There's no line here to end \maketitle. Please can someone help with this? I'm not sure what to do. Thank you.

```
% Thesis master document
\documentclass[final,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\textheight =24.2 cm 
\textwidth =15 cm 
\topmargin =-15mm

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage {mathrsfs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}

\def\hang{\hangindent\parindent}
\def\rf{\par\noindent\hang}

\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{result}{Result}


\begin{document}


    
    \baselineskip = 18pt
    
    \pagestyle{plain}
    
    \frontmatter
    
    \include{Title}
    \maketitle
    
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    %\listoffigures
    %\include{Introduction}
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \include{Chapter1}
    \include{Chapter2}
    \include{Chapter3}
    \include{Chapter4}
    %\include{Conclusion}
    %\include{Appendix}
    
    \backmatter
    
    \include{Bibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code isn't compilable, as there are includes of other files you don't provide. Please reduce your code as much as possible, in order to make it compilable and isolate the problem. Start by removing every include except one, and go from there.

Comment: @Juliet - Welcome to TeX.SE.  Since the title of your posting indicates that `\maketitle` is choking on something, we couldn't care less about the contents of the files `Chapter1.tex`, `Chapter2.tex`, ... or `Bibliography.tex`. Do please reveal what's in `Title.tex`, though, as that's the file that gets loaded immediately before `\maketitle` is executed.

Comment: Off-topic: There's absolutely no need to load the `epsfig` package.

Comment: Okay I have included what's in the title page.

Comment: @Juliet ok, start by removing all the `\\` in your title page that don't immediately follow text. Replace multiple consecutive `\\` with a `\vspace` of appropriate length, or with a `\vfill` (stretchable space that will evenly stretch across all the `\vfill` so that the page is full).

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to put font-macros inside of `\title` or `\author` (unless it's for single words, like `\title{How to \emph{not} kill the duck}`).

Comment: And in case you didn't know `\LARGE` and the other font-size macros don't take an argument but are switches, meaning they affect everything in the current group starting at that point. You don't want to use `\LARGE{JN}` but instead `{\LARGE JN}` (but the group should end with a `\par` if you want the baseline skip to be correct for `\LARGE`).

Comment: I was given this. I just put inputs into them. I'm even scared of making adjustments because the thesis is due in 2 hours and I've worked so hard to get here. I'll look at your comments, make a copy and go slowly.

Comment: @Juliet in that case: Can you please provide a picture of how your title page should look like (maybe with dummy contents)? I'll recreate it as closely as possible.

Comment: Hi Skillmon. I've attached the picture. Thank you.

Comment: Also, your acknowledgement will not show up on your title page as it currently is, but on a page before your title page.

Comment: okay. Can you please help resolve this?

Comment: I would if I knew where it should end up. Bottom of title page?

Comment: Acknowledgement should be just after the title page. On a new page. Thank you.

Comment: Also, while it's most likely too late to change it, but `\baselineskip=18pt` is most likely not what you want to do. If you need a bigger baseline skip what you usually should do is `\usepackage{setspace}` and then you use `\doublespacing`, or `\onehalfspacing`. But this will change the layout of your entire document, so nothing to change 90 min before your deadline.

Comment: Oh, and directly setting the page dimensions like `\textheight` etc. is discouraged as well, better use the `geometry` package (also, if your thesis comes out fine currently, don't change it just before your deadline...)

Comment: Yeah I really don't want to. Considering i've also sent a message to my supervisor and he is away from his computer is also distressing

Comment: Sorry to hear. I hope my answer helps. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks so much skillmon. I'm very grateful. I'll try it now

Comment: Hi Skillmon. Can you please clarify few things? Do i just paste all of this code into a page?

Comment: You just use my code instead of your main document file (if you didn't reduce your main file for this question, else, just remove your `\include{Title}` and `\maketitle` and then place the `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}` stuff and the `\chapter*{Acknowledgements}Praise and Glory` there). Oh, and if you want to have your Acknowledgements centred just put back your `\begin{center}...\end{center}` after `\chapter*{Acknowledgements}` (won't centre the heading, if that's needed, remove the `\chapter*` as well and use the manual formatting in your original `Title.tex` but change the `\LARGE`).

Comment: Thank you so much Skillmon. This works. You saved me. I cannot appreciate you enough. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. And you can always buy me a beer if we ever meet in real life as a thank you :P

Comment: Yeah you deserve one. Thank you Skillmon

Answer (score 2):

I would propose the following master file:

```
% Thesis master document
\documentclass[final,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\textheight =24.2 cm 
\textwidth =15 cm 
\topmargin =-15mm

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}

\def\hang{\hangindent\parindent}
\def\rf{\par\noindent\hang}

\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{result}{Result}


\begin{document}
    \baselineskip = 18pt
    
    \pagestyle{plain}
    
    \frontmatter
    
    \begin{titlepage}
      \centering
      \null
      \vfill
      \vfill
      {%
        \Huge\bfseries
        The Performance of Preliminary Model Selection Using AIC or BIC\par
      }%
      \vfill
      {%
        \LARGE
        Juliet Nwabuzor\par
      }%
      \vfill
      Supervised by Assoc.\@ Prof.\@ Paul Kabaila
      \vfill
      Department of Mathematical and Physical Sciences\\
      La Trobe University\\
      Victoria 3086, Australia\par
      \vspace{\baselineskip}
      October 2022
      \vfill
      \copyright Submitted in fulfilment of the thesis requirement of\\
      STA5THA and STA5THB, School of Computing, Engineering and\\
      Mathematical Sciences, La Trobe University.
      \vfill
      \vfill
      \null
    \end{titlepage}

    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    Praise and Glory
    
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    %\listoffigures
    %\include{Introduction}
    
    \mainmatter
    
    %\include{Chapter1}
    %\include{Chapter2}
    %\include{Chapter3}
    %\include{Chapter4}
    %\include{Conclusion}
    %\include{Appendix}
    
    \backmatter
    
    %\include{Bibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

This results in the following title page:

[image]

and the acknowledgements:

[image]